# AWS Cognito POST method to get token

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-cognito

I just want to make auth-api in Java Spring Boot application which need to communicate to AWS Cognito. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html this docs doesn't help me that much. I used to use Keycloak but this project required AWS Cognito and I have to say, docs is not that good.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of Cognito is a bit vague, but it adheres to OpenID Connect specifications. Hence, using the following autodiscovery URLs together with the OpenID specification should help you out:

```
https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/openid-configuration
https://cognito-idp.{region}.amazonaws.com/{userPoolId}/.well-known/jwks.json
```